# C# Garbage Collection Active Roots

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, clr

I'm reading about the C# garbage collector, and how the CLR builds object graphs.
The chapter references different roots that could be active for the object:

> •  References to global objects (though these are not allowed in C#, CIL
>   code does  permit allocation of global objects)
>   •  References to any
>   static objects/static fields
>   •  References to local objects within an
>   application’s code base
>   •  References to object parameters passed
>   into a method
>   •  References to objects waiting to be finalized
>   (described later in this chapter)
>   •  Any CPU register that references
>   an object

I was wondering if someone could give examples of these roots in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume you run the following program:

```
class Program
{
    static Class1 foo = new Class1();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class2 bar = new Class2();

        Class3 baz = new Class3();
        baz = null;

        Debugger.Break();

        bar.Run();
    }
}
```

When the program breaks into the debugger, there are 3+ objects that are not eligible for garbage collection because of the following references:

- a `Class1` object referenced by the static field `foo`
- a `string[]` object referenced by the parameter `args`
- zero or more `string` objects referenced by the `string[]` object referenced by `args`
- a `Class2` object referenced by the local variable `bar`

The `Class3` object is eligible for garbage collection and may already have been collected or be waiting to be finalized.

References to global objects are not allowed in C#. 
References in CPU registers are an implementation detail of the VM.

Comment: At this point `bar` may actually be eligible for collection in release mode since it isn't referenced after the break.

Comment: Brian is correct, `bar` would only be kept alive in *debug mode* for sure until the end of Main method, which is for debugging convenience only - in release mode `bar` may be collected.

Comment: I believe if you're running in DEBUG, objects are always safe until the function ends anyway.  I believe you're correct for optimized code though.

Comment: So the compiler would have looked ahead and seen it's not used again and marked it for collection?

Comment: @BenGale: The compiler optimizes the local variable away if the variable is never used.

Comment: What puzzles me is how the VM knows that a register is a reference and not an integer in case of a JIT-compiled method? GCs are such piece of wizardry...

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test
    {
        static object ImARoot = new object(); //static objects/static fields

        void foo(object paramRoot) // parameters  I'm a root to but only when in foo
        {
            object ImARoot2 = new object(); //local objects but only when I'm in foo. 

            //I'm a root after foo ends but only because GC.SuppressFinalize is not called called (typically in Dispose)
            SomethingWithAFinalizer finalizedRoot = new SomethingWithAFinalizer (); 


        }
    }
```

If you ever want to find out what an object is rooted to at a given point you can use [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) (in Visual Studio 2005 or later or in WinDbg) and use the !gcroot command.